# Svelte Flowbite Tooltip not showing prettified JSON

Tags: svelte

I am building a simple Svelte application to show JSON in a tooltip. However, it is not show prettified (nicely formatted) JSON.

I am using the [Flowbite Svelte Tooltip](https://flowbite-svelte.com/docs/components/tooltip).

**MyComponent.svelte**

```
<script>
    import { Tooltip } from 'flowbite-svelte'
    export let content
</script>

<div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <Tooltip arrow={true} type="custom" defaultClass="" class="p-4 font-medium bg-primary-100 w-2/5">
        {JSON.stringify(content, null, 4)}
    </Tooltip>
</div>
```

The tooltip is showing up fine but the JSON that is shown is all in a single line instead of being nicely formatted (human readable). I've tried `JSON.stringify(content, null, '\t')`

Like this:

[image]

How do I get the JSON to show up in the tooltip in a nicely formatted way and not all in a single line.

As a separate issue, the tooltip arrow is now appearing despite me having `arrow={true}` so not sure about that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of whitespace handling, setting [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to something like `pre-wrap` should work.